# jQuery $.getJSON not returning any data but getting status of 200 OK

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery 1.11.1 hosted by Google CDN and I am running a local simple server using `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` on my machine. Now jQuery is loading correctly and in my app I have the following code:

```
$('document').ready(function () {

    // let's get the products
    $.getJSON( 'scripts/products.js', function ( data ) {
        console.log('got here');
        console.log(data);
    });

})
```

at this stage I just want to be sure that I am receiving my JSON which is in the file scripts/products.js and contains the following code only:

```
[{
    product: "Product 1",
    size: "S",
    price: 10.99
},
{
    product: "Product 2",
    size: "M",
    price: 12.99
},
{
    product: "Product 3",
    size: "L",
    price: 13.99
}]
```

I am getting no error from the console and the dev tools are showing that the products file is being loaded! I am seeing a status of `200 OK`. So why aren't the console logs in my callback being called? If I try to loop through the data nothing happens?

Comment: can you add a fail handler and see whether it is getting called

Comment: That's no valid JSON.

Comment: if status is 200 then it should call\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've quoted isn't valid JSON. If jQuery is deferring to the browser's built-in `JSON.parse`, and the browser's `JSON.parse` is strict (as most are, I believe), although you're retrieving the text of the `products.js` file, the parsing fails. If you were using the [`fail` callback](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail/) of the returned promise, I expect you'd be seeing that get called.

In JSON, keys must be in double quotes:

```
[{
    "product": "Product 1",
    "size": "S",
    "price": 10.99
},
{
    "product": "Product 2",
    "size": "M",
    "price": 12.99
},
{
    "product": "Product 3",
    "size": "L",
    "price": 13.99
}]
```

Comment: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 2 column 5 of the JSON data - just seen that, thanks!